# Date API not accepting date format in a view filter

Tags: views, datetime

I'm using Availability Calendars and Date API modules and I need to filter views using the availability data. The module provides a view exposed filter which allows to choose an arrival and a departure dates. The problem is that when a date is chosen in the filter and the request is sent, a warning message appears saying:

> The value input for field Arrival date is invalid: The value 11 does
>   not match the expected format.

Its using the d/m/Y (15/02/2016) format in the field. If i change the parameters sent via GET in the url to Y-m-d format (2016-02-15) the message changes a little bit but still not working:

> The value input for field Arrival date is invalid: The value 2016-02-5
>   00:00 does not match the expected format. The value input for field
>   Departure date is invalid: The value 2016-02-15 00:00 does not match
>   the expected format.

When I check the Drupal logs, the error messages point to Date API module:

> Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   date_default_date() (line 115 of
>   /var/www/vhosts/drupal/litoral.interdigital.biz/sites/all/modules/date/date_api/date_api_elements.inc).
>
> Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   date_default_date() (line 114 of
>   /var/www/vhosts/drupal/litoral.interdigital.biz/sites/all/modules/date/date_api/date_api_elements.inc).
>
> Notice: Undefined index: time in date_popup_input_date() (line 626 of
>   /var/www/vhosts/drupal/litoral.interdigital.biz/sites/all/modules/date/date_popup/date_popup.module).

The first two warnings appear twice every time a request is sent which looks like they're triggered by both arrival and departure dates. The last one occurs only once.

I've been Googling for the problem and I found some references to invalid dates and Date API but they weren't very useful to me. I tried to define date formats in the as shown in: https://www.drupal.org/node/2243009 but nothing happened.

Edit:

I followed the issue to the date_api.module and the parse function (line 596). That function defines the error message "The value 2016-02-15 00:00 does not match the expected format" . from here I coukld obtain the `$format` parameter of this function and I've seen that it's "Y", I tried to pass years as GET parameters for the function but still nothing. If i force the `$format` to be "d/m/Y" or "Y-m-d" the message changes to:

> The value input for field Arrival date is invalid.
>
> The value 2016-02-15 00:00 does not match the expected format.
>
> The day is missing.
>
> The month is missing.
>
> The year is missing.
>
> The hour is missing.
>
> The minute is missing.
>
> The value input for field Departure date is invalid.
>
> The value 2016-02-15 00:00 does not match the expected format.
>
> The day is missing.
>
> The month is missing.
>
> The year is missing.
>
> The hour is missing.
>
> The minute is missing.